# While loop asking two times for input() entry in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I use Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:28:38).

First of all my script is running correctly the second time I enter a correct entry in `input()`, but I prefer it asks only once.
In my code I wrote `print()` lines in order to see what is happening in real time and that's where I don't get what happens in the execution.

Let's see the script:

```
import subprocess
from scrapy import cmdline
import sys

champ_choix = ""
while champ_choix != "1" and champ_choix != "2":
    champ_choix=input("Pour cat_course tapez 1\nPour hippodrome tapez 2\n")
    print("L'input est : {}".format(champ_choix)) #the input is:
    print("le type de l'input est: {}".format(type(champ_choix))) #the type of input is:
    if champ_choix == "1": #Traite le champ hippodrome
        print("on a le champ_choix 1") #we have got choice 1
        #do instructions
        sys.exit() #to stop the script and stop asking once again an entry after it is done
    if champ_choix == "2":
        print("le champ_choix est 2") #we have got choice 2
        cmdline.execute(['scrapy','crawl','test_shell','-a','nom_prix=True'])
        sys.exit()
```

Now what I have in the terminal is:

```
Pour cat_course tapez 1
Pour hippodrome tapez 2
2 # here a good entry
L'input est : 2 # it says it is a good entry
le type de l'input est: <class 'str'> # it even says that's the good type
le champ_choix est 2 # it even says it is in the second `if` condition
Pour cat_course tapez 1 # but it asks once again, without executing instructions
Pour hippodrome tapez 2
2 # a good entry once more
L'input est : 2
le type de l'input est: <class 'str'>
le champ_choix est 2 # in the second `if` condition and now gonna finally execute instructions
#Running the spider as expected, that is alright
#Stop and exit, it is alright too
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Use `break` instead of `sys.exit()`. Otherwise, when I ran this script, it asked me input only once.

Answer (score 1):

Well worded question (props for giving the stdout) but make sure you are doing proper spacing (i.e. there should be a space before and after operators such as `a == b`).

1) Don't use `sys.exit()` just use `break`.

2) You need to prime your loop. In other words do one input before you
enter the loop then keep inputting at the END of your loop:

```
import subprocess
from scrapy import cmdline
import sys

while True: 
    champ_choix = input("Pour cat_course tapez 1\nPour hippodrome tapez 2\n")

    # This first if isn't needed because the if at the bottom catches this case
    # if champ_choix == "1": #Traite le champ hippodrome
    #     break
    if champ_choix == "2":
        cmdline.execute(['scrapy','crawl','test_shell','-a','nom_prix=True'])
    if champ_choix in ["1", "2"]:
        break
```

Comment: while champ_choix not in ["1", "2"] :)

Comment: I changed as you shown, but after I entered the input it stoped simply and did not execute instructions, it did not print "le champ_choix est 2" as it must.

Comment: @AvyWam see my update.  What you needed was `do while` not a simple `while` and I wan't paying attention.

Comment: Ok. I did as you wrote. Changing for `while True` and put `if champ_choix == "2":` at first, because in the contrary it doesn't work as expected, and `if champ_choix in ["1", "2"]:` at last, and I remove the `break` key word in `if champ_choix == "2":`  too, exactly as you did. The script works, but it asks me two times again. And to be honest, in `if champ_choix in ["1", "2"]:` there is another while loop and I commented it to see if by "magic" it would be due to that but actually it is not the root of the repetition issue.

Comment: @AvyWam Seems to [work right](https://repl.it/repls/CoarseSympatheticCalculator). Is there a test case I am missing?  (Did you remove the `input` above the `while` loop)?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse That's a great thing you show me the website repl.it because when I enter my own code, it works fine too, it asks me only once. So it means the issue is not in the script itself. But what it could be?... Ouch it will be hard to find, and maybe I will just be resigned to enter twice.

Comment: Is there more code you aren't showing? Is this in a `.py` file and are you running this file from terminal or `import`ing from something? Add a `print` above your `while` loop. It sounds like this code is being run twice from an external source. Or you haven't saved your file yet and are trying to run an older version of your file.

Comment: No really, at the top there is only the `import` modules, I just avoided to write I use `pymongo` and connect to the database, that is for the `champ_choix == "1"` and the instructions in it are only related to database instructions and that's why I did not wrote about it because that's useless for the reader of stackoverflow and the issue itself I guess, and there is nothing after `champ_choix == "2"` except the own instructions of `champ_choix == "2"` of course. But nothing more.

Comment: Could it be you are not running the python script that you are currently editting?

Comment: LMAO, common no! I only have one script in this `spiders` folder, it is called `corrections.py` the other `.py` files are only class spiders theirselves. So you cannot execute it with python interpreter as I wrote it. Really I am not so head in the coulds. What you asked could be a possibility, but actually it is not the case.

Comment: It happens to the best of us which is why I am checking. Sorry man I don't have any other solutions.

Comment: Too bad, you tried that's very nice from you. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Apparently this is related to the tree view. In the project spider of scrapy, you have `project/spiders`. In the the directory `project` you have a `__init__.py` file, an `items.py` file, etc, automatically. In spiders you have automatically a `__init__.py` too, and you make the files you want where you create your `class spider`. When I put my file called `corrections.py`, the current file of this topic, in the directory `spiders`, the bug occurs. When I put in the parent directory `project`, the bug does not occur. That's still mysterious why for me but now that's ok.